# Invalid cast from IDirect3DSurface to SoftwareBitmap

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

I try to implement processing frames from webcam to the WPF application using UWP API.
There is article how to work with MediaCapture & MediaFrameReader:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/process-media-frames-with-mediaframereader#handle-the-frame-arrived-event

If I set up MemoryPreference to cpu, SoftwareBitmaps are initialized to the null in the event. When I place Auto, I can see IDirect3DSurface objects are in the event, but in conversion to the SoftwareBitmap the exception "Specified cast is not valid." is raised.

How to convert IDirect3DSurface to SoftwareBitmap?

```
private async void MediaCaptureExample()
{
    var frameSourceGroups = await MediaFrameSourceGroup.FindAllAsync();

    MediaFrameSourceGroup selectedGroup = null;
    MediaFrameSourceInfo colorSourceInfo = null;

    foreach (var sourceGroup in frameSourceGroups)
    {
        foreach (var sourceInfo in sourceGroup.SourceInfos)
        {
            if (sourceInfo.MediaStreamType == MediaStreamType.VideoRecord && sourceInfo.SourceKind == MediaFrameSourceKind.Color)
            {
                colorSourceInfo = sourceInfo;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (colorSourceInfo != null)
        {
            selectedGroup = sourceGroup;
            break;
        }
    }

    capture = new MediaCapture();

    var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings()
    {
        SourceGroup = selectedGroup,
        SharingMode = MediaCaptureSharingMode.ExclusiveControl,
        MemoryPreference = MediaCaptureMemoryPreference.Auto,
        StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video
    };

    await capture.InitializeAsync(settings);

    var colorFrameSource = capture.FrameSources[colorSourceInfo.Id];

    var preferredFormat = colorFrameSource.SupportedFormats.Where(format =>
    {
        return format.VideoFormat.Width >= 1080
        && String.Compare(format.Subtype, MediaEncodingSubtypes.Mjpg, true) == 0;

    }).FirstOrDefault();

    if (preferredFormat == null)
    {
        // Our desired format is not supported
        return;
    }

    await colorFrameSource.SetFormatAsync(preferredFormat);

    mediaFrameReader = await capture.CreateFrameReaderAsync(colorFrameSource);
    mediaFrameReader.FrameArrived += MediaFrameReader_FrameArrived;
    var result = await mediaFrameReader.StartAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("Result = " + result.ToString());
}

private void MediaFrameReader_FrameArrived(MediaFrameReader sender, MediaFrameArrivedEventArgs args)
{
    try
    {
        var mediaFrameReference = sender.TryAcquireLatestFrame();
        var videoMediaFrame = mediaFrameReference?.VideoMediaFrame;
        var softwareBitmap = videoMediaFrame?.SoftwareBitmap;
        var direct3DSurface = videoMediaFrame?.Direct3DSurface;

        if (direct3DSurface != null)
        {
            var softwareBitmapTask = SoftwareBitmap.CreateCopyFromSurfaceAsync(mediaFrameReference.VideoMediaFrame.Direct3DSurface).AsTask();
            softwareBitmap = softwareBitmapTask.Result;
        }

        if (softwareBitmap != null)
        {
            using (var stream = new Windows.Storage.Streams.InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
            {
                var encoderTask = BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, stream).AsTask();
                encoderTask.Wait();
                var encoder = encoderTask.Result;
                encoder.SetSoftwareBitmap(softwareBitmap);
                Task t = encoder.FlushAsync().AsTask();
                t.Wait();
                var image = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();

                image.BeginInit();
                image.StreamSource = stream.AsStream();
                image.CacheOption = System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                image.EndInit();

                imageElement.Source = image;
            }
        }
    } 
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in format subtype. I changed format from Mjpg to Nv12, and everything start working properly (even for MediaCaptureMemoryPreference.Auto):

```
var preferredFormat = colorFrameSource.SupportedFormats.Where(format =>
{
    return format.VideoFormat.Width >= 1080 && String.Compare(format.Subtype, MediaEncodingSubtypes.Nv12, true) == 0;
}).FirstOrDefault();
```